# Hide binary portion in mixed text-binary file

Tags: binary-file

I have a self-extracting "archive" generated by [Makeself](http://makeself.io/) tool, which is essentially a shell script with a large binary blob in inside. What I want is to view only text part of the file, while hiding the binary part completely (possibly abbreviating it to one line).

If there is a way to speed up the process of opening such file by preventing `vim` from reading binary portion, that's even better. Currently, I have to use `less` for viewing such files, because `vim` just takes too long to load.

Comment: Maybe one possibility would be to add comments with fold markers around the binary part (`# {{{` and `# }}}`) and a modeline as the first line of your file `# vim fdm:marker` this way vim will fold this part. The problem is that I don't know makeself and don't know if you can make it add these lines.

Comment: @statox I also don't know `Makeself`, and I wouldn't make such script in the first place. The point is, I want a solution that will work with files I receive from other people. Possibly, a way to make `vim` discard everything after first binary character, although not ideal, would probably be sufficient.

Comment: Oh I didn't understand that you wasn't the one generating the file. Maybe you can set `foldmethod` to `expr` and use `fold-expr` to match non ascii characters.

Comment: @statox Thanks for the advice. I'll look into that. Some research is in order, though. `fold-expr` syntax currently looks like a black magic to me.

Comment: [`:h fold-expr`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/fold.txt.html#fold%2dexpr) gives good explainations: the expression you give to `foldexpr` is evaluated for each line of the file (that you can reference to `v:lnum`) and should return an integer (positive or negative) or some other strings that are explained in the doc. Depending on what is return, vim will fold or not the line. [This vimcast](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/writing-a-custom-fold-expression/) should also help you. If I find some free time I'll see if I can write one for you.